# Change freehub body from road to MTB on DT Swiss hub, possible?

Tags: freehub, dtswiss

Generally, [it is possible to change the freehub body to different standards on DT Swiss hubs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yu_LSSj_SBk). However, their website only shows examples of swapping between various road-specific standards, or various MTB-specific standards.

Is it possible to swap from a road standard to an MTB standard?

To make this question more concrete, is it possible to change a [GR 1600 Spline](https://www.dtswiss.com/en/wheels/wheels-road/gravel/gr-1600-spline) rear wheel, which comes with a 350 hub, to use a Shimano Micro Spline freehub body?

Comment: I've emailed DT in the past asking about "unlisted" fhb and endcap configurations and they've been helpful. I recommend starting there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DT Swiss support got back to me. They said that it is possible to make the conversion. For this one needs to get the Micro Spline freehub and the Micro Spline endcap. However, the following caveat was mentioned:

> But you'll have to consider the 1 mm narrow total length of your drive train (141 mm instead of 142 mm). Because MTB Freehubs are 1mm more narrow than road freehubs.